# Infinite do..while loop in Java

Tags: java, do-while

Can someone explain why? I always encounter an infinite loop when I use a do-while loop. What am I missing?

```
package com.assignment2;

public class FooCorporation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        employee(9.50, 55);
        employee(8.20, 47);
        employee(10.00, 73);

    }

    public static void employee(double basePay, int hoursWorked) {

        double salary = 0;
        int overtimeHours = 40;

        do {
            if (basePay >= 8.00 || hoursWorked > 40 ) {
                if (hoursWorked > 40) {
                    salary = basePay * hoursWorked
                            * ((hoursWorked - overtimeHours) * 1.5);
                } else {
                    salary = basePay * hoursWorked;
                }

            }

            else 
                System.out.println("According to law: Base Pay should be more than $8.00");

            System.out.printf("Total Pay: %d %.2f\n", hoursWorked, salary);

        } while (hoursWorked <= 60);

    }

}
```

Comment: housrWorked isn't changing.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't' be infinite?

Comment: This post should have been marked as Homework ;-)

Comment: Nope, not homework... just practicing some MIT assignments. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-introduction-to-programming-in-java-january-iap-2010/assignments/MIT6_092IAP10_assn02.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're never modifying `hoursWorked`'s value so the condition is always met, hence the infinite loop. You'll want to increment it's value at the end of each iteration, after

```
    else 
        System.out.println("According to law: Base Pay should be more than $8.00");

    System.out.printf("Total Pay: %d %.2f\n", hoursWorked, salary);

    //Right here
} while (hoursWorked <= 60);
```

**Edit** Just as an extra mile, I'm not getting the meaning of that loop. When would you increase `hoursWorked`'s value? Shouldn't that be something related to a particular employee? Seems like if you wanted to do that for every employe who worked 60 hours or less. In that case you should have a list of `Employee` objects and iterate over them, picking up only the eployees who worked the amount of hours you want.

Comment: Thanks, Just got rid of the do-while and used if-else statements...so much easier.

Comment: @Appsheriff That's why I wasn't getting the meaning of the loop :). You're welcome pal.

Answer (score 1):

`hoursWorked` never changes, so your loop condition is never false.

Answer (score 1):

The value of hoursWorked is never changed. It is always less than or equal to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition is never met to stop. You're not modifying the value of hoursWorked in the loop, so it will run infiintely. However, if you pass in a value > 60, then it would execute only once.

Answer (score 0):

The way you designed the code it looks like that you do not need a `do-while loop` block at all as your are not changing the `hoursworked` value at all.